# Deprecated API usage: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, autodesk-forge, revit-api, pdf.js

I have a Forge Viewer integration (v. 7) in my Vue and Nuxt.js app. Recently, my company decided to upgrade our Revit files to version 2022, and since then we haven't been able to load the 'viewables'/child nodes of the svf file in the GUI viewer. The 3D model renders correctly, but not the 2D views, and the only thing to go off is the console message:

`'Deprecated API usage: No "GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc" specified.'`

The message is logged within pdf.js, an external script loaded in via Autodesk.Extensions, that i don't have direct control over. After debugging this script, i can indeed see that the workerSrc property is not set (it is an empty string). I can see in the Forge Viewer documentation that a PDF extension exists for the v7 viewer, but the usage example provided doesn't give me any useful insight regarding this issue.

I have been reading the migration guide for Forge Viewer v6 -> v7, but haven't found anything obvious that can relieve this error.

I tried to compare the manifest files from previous Revit versions with the new 2022, and the only difference i can see are two new properties added to each node in the 2022 version:

```
isVectorPDF: true
units: mm
```

Seeing as my 'error' occurs in a pdf related script, and seeing this new attribute added to the manifest files, i assume those two are somehow related and are causing the issue.

Similar posts to this one suggest that i require/import the pdf script in my project, either from node modules or a CDN, and then explicitly set the workerSrc value. But since i don't have access to this script directly, how can i go about setting the value of this property?

Comment: Can you please try with a simple Viewer app (no customizations)? You can try at viewer.autodesk.com. One big difference in v7 is how to load: `viewer.loadDocumentNode`.