# 2D viewables from Revit 2022 models do not work in the Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We have a Forge Viewer (GuiViewer3D, v. 7) implementation in our Nuxt app, using a few extensions (MarkupsCore, Measure, FullScreen) and custom docking panels such as a list of viewables to select from. Ever since we upgraded from Revit version 2021 to 2022, we haven't been able to display the 2D viewables from our svf files in the viewer. When we select any 2D viewable, the viewer freezes in this state:

[image]

With a few warnings thrown in the console:

```
Deprecated API usage: No “GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc” specified.
```

and

```
Warning: getOperatorList - ignoring errors during "GetOperatorList: page 0" task: "r: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'X')"
```

of which the former lead to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292482/deprecated-api-usage-no-globalworkeroptions-workersrc-specified) stackoverflow post, to which Augusto Goncalves suggested we tried uploading our revit file in your online viewer at https://viewer.autodesk.com/designviews. This works, and so we tried to create a new Nuxt app with a simple Forge Viewer implementation following the v. 7 example guide. This also works.

What we did next was to re-implement the v. 7 viewer in our production app by following the official documentation once again, thus removing any customization and leaving out everything else than the bare minimum. With this v. 7 viewer, running in a node environment on either node version 10.0 or 14.9, the bug persists, ruling out the possibility of any custom code being the cause.

Upon further debugging of scripts (loaded in via Autodesk) such as pdf.js, CompGeom.min.js, PDFLoader.js, path2d.js etc., we’ve gotten to a point where this message appears, and this is where our current trail ends:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'X') at c.strokeClipperContour (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/CompGeom/CompGeom.min.js:17:173979) at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/CompGeom/CompGeom.min.js:17:177686  at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/CompGeom/CompGeom.min.js:17:177811 at Array.map (<anonymous>) at c.fill (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/CompGeom/CompGeom.min.js:17:177413) at t.value https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/CompGeom/CompGeom.min.js:17:16067)  at t.value (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/CompGeom/CompGeom.min.js:17:9554) at e.beginDrawing (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/PDF/PDF.min.js:39:211570) at t.value (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/PDF/PDF.min.js:39:185323)  at ttps://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/PDF/PDF.min.js:39:158419
```

We cannot effectively debug these minified scripts, and are hoping you can provide some insight as to what might be causing this issue.

Comment: So, it sounds like this issue happens with your previous Nuxt app only? When you tested with new Nuxt  app, is that the same structure, or the new one embeds Forge Viewer with all built-in extensions and UI, while the previous one is based on bared Forge Viewer?

Comment: from your description, the 2D viewrable of Revit 2022  has no problem, however it cannot work with previous Nuxt app. In addition, I do not get why it also throws of PDF.  Is this 2D viewerable is an embedded PDF inside Revit?

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Hi, thanks for your answer! It turned out to be a problem in our own code base, registering array prototype functions that conflicted with methods somewhere else. So we managed to fix the issue.